# The word for "usually" in Mandarin

Tags: word-choice

In Mandarin, there are many words to express the meaning "usually" - 通常，平常，平日，素，率，素来，往往，常，etc... (actually there are way more, but I don't list all of them here).

There are too many to choose the correct word. How are all of them different and more importantly, how can I know which word fits the best for my specific purpose?

<sup>At least for me it feels that 通常 and 平常 are used more often, but I'm not sure.</sup>

For example, in these contexts:

> Do you usually go to the cafe?
>
> What do you usually do after work?
>
> Do you usually come to Shanghai on your holiday?

In these cases, how can I know which one to use? Or are these more or less the same and which to choose does not affect that much?

Comment: see online dictionaries, bkrs: 通常#2750，常 #3352， **平日** ordinarily
usually
on ordinary days（一般的日子） ordinary days (as distinguished from holidays, festivals, etc.)
（平时） everyday; week day #6073 **素副**
（素来;向来） usually; habitually; always:
平素 usually
青藏高原素有世界屋脊之称。 The Qinghai-Xizang Plateau has long been known as the roof of the world.，*率 bound morpheme,大率如此。 This is usually the case. **素来** always; usually; all along:
他素来不吸烟。 He never smokes.
他素来守法。 He always abides by the law.#25421往往（see Q&A for 往往 and 常常） **常** （bound morpheme when used as adverb))(1) 经常, 常常 [frequently; often]

Comment: 通常、一般 can be used in all 3 proposed sentences

Comment: @user6065 How about 平常 and 平时?

Comment: see examples in online dictionaries, anyhow comments #1,2 only copy parts of online dictionaries (or as far as "bound morpheme" is concerned may draw the necessary conclusion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like "usually, typically, normally and often" in English, "通常, 平日, 素来, 往往 and 常常" In Chinese have overlapping meanings but they all have subtle differences with each others.

> "通常" = usually /typically (*emphasizes on normalcy*)
>
> Example : "他通常不做好事" (usually, he doesn't do good things - *not doing good things to him is normal*)

~

> "平日"= "in normal days/ normally"  (*emphasizes on regularity*)
>
> Example : "他平日不做好事" (normally, he doesn't do good things  - *it is a regular routine for him to not do the good things*)

~

> "素/ 素来" = "always" (*emphasizes on constancy*)
>
> Example : "他素来不做好事" (always, he doesn't do good things- *he has always been like that* )

~

> "往往" = "often" (*implies 'ironically'*)
>
> Example : "他往往不做好事" (often, he doesn't do good things- *despite other's expectation* )

~

> "常/ 常常 " = often  (*implies more often than not*)
>
> Example : "他常常不做好事" (often, he doesn't do good things- *he is like that more often than not*)